# Let $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$. Also $\Gamma \subseteq \Omega$. Show that $\bigcap \Omega \subseteq \bigcap \Gamma.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $\Gamma$, $\Omega$ be collection of sets and $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$. Also $\Gamma \subseteq \Omega$. Show that $\bigcap \Omega \subseteq \bigcap \Gamma.$

My solution: Let the set $X \in \Gamma$ so that $X \in \Omega$. Let $z \in \bigcap \Omega$, so that $z \in Y$ for all $Y \in \Omega$. So $z \in X$. This further implies that $z \in W$ for all $W \in \Gamma$, that is, $z \in \bigcap \Gamma$.

Can anyone pinpoint any mistake or shortcoming in the proof, or recommend a better way to do it?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Your $X$ is irrelevant, the point is the relationship between $Y$ and $W$.  Otherwise OK.

Comment: How is $X$ used in your proof? For me, “*Let $z \in \bigcap \Omega$, so that $z \in Y$ for all $Y \in \Omega$. This further implies that $z \in W$ for all $W \in \Gamma$, that is, $z \in \bigcap \Gamma$.*” is a reasonable proof.

Answer (score 2):

A possibly better way is as follows.

*Proof*. Since

$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
x\in \bigcap\Omega&\Leftrightarrow&\text{for all }X\in\Omega\text{, we have }x\in X&\text{by the definition of }\bigcap\\
&\Rightarrow&\text{for all }X\in\Gamma\text{, we have }x\in X&\text{by }\Gamma\subseteq \Omega\\
&\Leftrightarrow&x\in \bigcap\Gamma&\text{by the definition of }\bigcap,
\end{array}
$$

then $\bigcap\Omega\subseteq\bigcap\Gamma$.